# Controlling pod recovery from "Error: ImagePullBackOff" when Contrainer Registry is also inaccessible

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-pod, container-registry

We had a major outage when both our container registry and the entire K8S cluster lost power. When the cluster recovered faster than the container registry, my pod (part of a statefulset) is stuck in  `Error: ImagePullBackOff`.

Is there a config setting to retry downloading the image from the CR periodically or recover without manual intervention?

I looked at `imagePullPolicy` but that does not apply for a situation when the CR is unavailable.

Comment: It does retry periodically, but the frequency that it tries decreases the more failures it has.

Comment: Is there a way to control this or at least get a status about when it tries next? Otherwise, I assume this is hidden somewhere

Comment: `kubectl get events -A` will show when its attempted. Not sure about figuring out next pull

Comment: Maybe if you configure the deployment via some CI/CD tool, you can check at the pipeline level if the deployment fails, you can create another deployment that points to a mirror registry...or use a service like `Harbor` https://goharbor.io/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The  `BackOff`  part in `ImagePullBackOff`  status means that Kubernetes is keep trying to pull the image from the registry, with an exponential back-off delay (10s, 20s, 40s, …). The delay between each attempt is increased until it reaches a compiled-in limit of 300 seconds (5 minutes) - more on it in [Kubernetes docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/containers/images/#imagepullbackoff).

`backOffPeriod` parameter for the image pulls is a hard-coded constant in Kuberenets and unfortunately is not tunable now, as it can affect  the node performance - otherwise, it can be adjusted in the very [code](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/5f920426103085a28069a1ba3ec9b5301c19d075/pkg/kubelet/kubelet.go#L155) for your custom kubelet binary.
There is still ongoing [issue](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/57291) on making it adjustable.

Comment: Thank you very much for the comprehensive answer! Really appreciate the links to the source code too! I think there's a potential bug related to the MaxContainerBackOff hard coded 300s as I had to restart my Statefulset to trigger the image download after over 20 minutes.